# galaxy note N7000 wifi disconnect and forgot wifi network

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-note

i'm connecting to wifi home spot and after phone screen turn off wifi disconnect and forgot pasword ... in settings about wifi and sleep stays "Never"

Comment: So every time your phone goes to sleep, it disconnects from the wifi and forgets the wifi encryption key?

Comment: yes, right @John